# Is there any way to create a node(slave) automatically to build jobs of particular project?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

As the topic's title, I would like to create Jenkins node automatically to build jobs for a particular project. Example: I have 3 projects (Java, NodeJS, .NET) and I would like to build these projects on separate nodes. My scenario here is:

When I start to build one of these project, Jenkins will check the node with given label name(node name), if the node doesn't exist then Jenkins will create one with given label name.

My question here is how to create a Jenkins node automatically with Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: I assume you are using some cloud provider for your nodes. You can use the configuration in the “cloud” section of Jenkins and provide labels. The plug-in such as AWS ec2 can handle this scenario. I’m your Jenkins file, enclose stages in a node block with the label of your choice. Do not forget to set a ttl to nodes so that they are cleaned up upon usage to avoid side effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you referring on demand node scale/down, I am not sure how to do it, but better and long term solution for managing multiple runtime/dependencies would be to execute your pipeline stages into the containers, which is what most of the CI/CD tools does now days